# how to use link path to set the background face?

Tags: org-mode, faces

I would like to use a custom link, i.e. [[h:blue][blue highlighted text]], to create highlighted text. The background color of the highlighted text is specified by the path. I have

```
(org-link-set-parameters
 "h"
 :export (lambda (path desc backend)
       (cond
    ((eq 'html backend)
     (format "<span style=\"background-color: %s\">%s</span>" path (or desc ""))
     )))
 ;:face `(:foreground ,(lambda (path) (format "%s" path)))
 :face '(:background "yellow")     
 )
```

The export works as expected, but I need to hard-code the background face to make any sort of highlighting. How can I fix this statement?

```
 :face `(:foreground ,(lambda (path) (format "%s" path)))
```

so the path can specify the color in emacs?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer

```
(defun path-color (path)
  (list :background path))
```

then update the face statement to

```
 :face 'path-color
```

I based my answer by reviewing the last example of http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2016/11/04/New-link-features-in-org-9/. I don't understand why list is needed.

Comment: you don't "need' a list, you could also return `(:background ,path) I think.